# What is difference between $this->Products and $this->Products() in laravel model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I got different result from `getReward1` and `getReward2`:

**Model**:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'user_id');
    }

    public function getReward1()
    {
        return $this
        ->Products
        ->where('reward', '>', 0)
        ->where('status', 0)
        ->sum('reward'); // sum = 7,690,000
    }

    public function getReward2()
    {
        return $this
        ->Products()
        ->where('reward', '>', 0)
        ->where('status', 0)
        ->sum('reward'); // sum = 7,470,000
    }
}
```

`getReward1` return 7,690,000 and `getReward2` return 7,470,000 (Two different values)

What is difference between `$this->Products` and `$this->Products()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
$this->products; 
// Returns a Collection

$this->products(); 
// Returns a Relation instance, which is a query builder and can be of type HasMany, BelongsTo...

$this->products()->get(); 
// Is EXACTLY like doing $this->products for the first time.
```

The main difference is that `products()` is just a query that hasn't been executed yet, whereas `products` are the actual results of this query.

Honestly, even if the name is the same and can be confusing, there are no other similarities between them.

A simple analogy:

```php
DB::table('products')->where('user_id', 18); //could be the $user->products()

DB::table('products')->where('user_id', 18)->get(); //could be $user->products
```

It's just an analogy, it's not exactly like this internally, but you get the point.

To add more confusion on top of it, Collection methods are ofter similar to those you find in queries; both have `where()`, `first()`...

The main thing to remember is that with parentheses, you are still building a query. Until you call `get` or `first`, you remain in a query builder.

Without, you already have your results, you are in a Collection (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections).

---

About the difference you get between `getReward1` and `getReward2`, it's hard to tell exactly what's happening without seeing your database structure.

It can be a lot of things, but when you are calling the `sum` method, you are calling it on a Collection instance in `getReward1` and on a query builder in `getReward2` (you are actually executing a query with `SELECT SUM(reward)...`).

Comment: Thank you so much. I think `return $this->Products->where('reward', '>', 0)->where('status', 0)` does not apply all of where conditions. While with the `DB::table('products')->where('reward', '>', 0)->where('status', 0)` or `$this->Products()->where()->where()` returns the most correct result.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->Products()` will return an instance of the query builder. The subsequence `where` clauses will constrain the DB query and then return only the product that you want. These will not be stored in the model instance.

`$this->Products` will get all of the products from the DB and store them in the model instance as an Eloquent Collection. The subsequent where clauses will then be performed on the Eloquent Collection.

Essentially, the method is doing everything in the DB, whereas, the property is fetching all of the rows and then limiting it with PHP.